# What happens when a Reward that is a character card loses its hitpoints?

Tags: sentinels-of-the-multiverse

While playing the *Oblivaeon* expansion to *Sentinels of the Multiverse*, we completed the Mission card “Time and Time Again”, giving us the Reward character card “The Chronoist”. He has 14 HP.

Unfortunately, he was also destroyed by losing all his hit points. What happens to him then? Does he go into my trash? Get removed from the game? Something else?

Answer (score 0):

From looking I see a thread on board game geek the card goes to the hero's trash when destroyed.

https://videogamegeek.com/thread/2074878/incapacitation-and-rewards

> 2) The Reward card is killed. It is sent to that hero's trash. When that hero is incapacitated, does the trashed Reward card go under the hero's character card as well? It SEEMS that way, since no exception is made for trashed rewards in the Incapacitation rules section

The response to this in the thread is that it is correct

Comment: I assume that when the trashed character is incapacitated, it still goes under their character card? And if the trash gets shuffled into the character deck, this gets shuffled too?

Comment: @Thunderforge I am not sure about the second part of the question but it seems that way from the link. I have not personally ran into this situation in my limited experience with the digital version